# Why browser network shows messages body and headers, after using https/ssl

Tags: .net, ssl, https

We have implemented SSL in our project. When we run the application on HTTPS and open the devtools network tab shows all message body and headers as it is.
My question is,

1. When SSL is enabled and site is running on HTTPS scheme then why it is not encrypting the message body and headers?
2. When and how it encrypts/secure the request? Is it in the network i.e. in LAN or..?

**General**

Request URL: https://XXX--XXXXX--XXX/api/Login/Authenticate/?

Request Method: POST

Status Code: 200 OK

Remote Address: xx.xx.xxx.xxx:443

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response Headers**

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,UserId,Platform

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Cache-Control: no-cache

Connection: Keep-Alive

Content-Length: 479

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Date: Wed, 16 Oct 2019 06:58:10 GMT

Expires: -1

Pragma: no-cache

Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5

X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

**Request Headers**

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,mr;q=0.8

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 53

Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Host: XXXX--XXXX

Origin: XXXXXXXX

Referer: https://xx-xxx-xxx--xxxx-xx/xxx

Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)

UserID: ABC.XYZ

**Request Payload**
{Username: "ABC.XYZ", Password: "ABC.XYZ"}

Password: "ABC.XYZ"

Username: "xyzabc"

Comment: "why it is not encrypting the message body and headers?" It does. Then the *browser*, which has to render the content *decrypts* it. If it didn't, the site wouldn't work. So, of course when you're *inside* the browser dev tools, you have access to the decrypted content.

Comment: Thank you so much @Damien_The_Unbeliever .  understood (y)